# Error al intentar compilar un programa en java mediante el terminal de windows

Tags: java

Tengo este Hola mundo:

```
public class HolaMundo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo!);
    }
}`
```

El cual está en un archivo llamado HolaMundo.java, y para intentar compilarlo escribo lo siguiente:

```
javac HolaMundo.java
```

pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
javac: file not found: HolaMundo.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

El archivo está en el escritorio, por lo que el directorio que tengo seleccionado es el desktop (\Desktop>)

Comment: ¿Si lo ejecutas con Powershell sí compila?

Comment: Por el error parece que no tienes bien configuraradas las variables de entorno.